# What can I do with the Super-Secret Canadian Mind-Control Device?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

So, the mind-control device has a dial that goes up to eleven. If I pick a number, and then "Touch that Dial!", I just get a message that says "You switch the dial. All of the monsters in the kingdom suddenly perk up their ears, as though receiving secret instructions."

What sort of secret instructions are they receiving? What does this device do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Super-Secret Canadian Mind-Control Device](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Super-Secret_Canadian_Mind-Control_Device), when activated, adds the number on its dial to the level of every monster you fight. There are also certain special drops you can receive from bosses if you defeat them with the dial on certain settings. That table is specified in the wiki link above, but if needed I can reproduce it here.